# On MacOS, what character does `Esc+` or `+Esc` correspond to in Bash, when using iTerm2 terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, gnu, readline, macos

I've read that mapping `Left Option` key to `Esc+` should fix many of the issues users of Bash, on MacOS, have with GNU Readline key-bindings.

However, I've never encountered `Esc+` or `+Esc` before, so does it mean `Esc`, `Meta`, `Ctrl`, or something else? How can I test what key my `Left Option` is mapped to after enabled `Esc+` or `+Esc`?

[image: "]